# как записать JSON массив в csv на php

Tags: php, json, csv

```
три массива в JSON формате: properties, values и items
в properties и в values массивы в виде [ключ, значение]
в items - код товара и массив из ключей свойств и значений

Пример:
{"properties":
[[24,"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0446\u0435\u0441\u0441\u043e\u0440"],
[29,"\u041e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043c \u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u043f\u0430\u043c\u044f\u0442\u0438, \u041c\u0411"],
[42,"\u0422\u0438\u043f \u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u043f\u0430\u043c\u044f\u0442\u0438"],
[318,"\u0416\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0441\u043a, \u0413\u0411"],
[320,"\u041e\u043f\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0434"],
[322,"\u0412\u0435\u0431-\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430"],
[323,"\u041e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430"],
[325,"\u0411\u0430\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0435\u044f"],
[328,"\u0426\u0432\u0435\u0442"],
[433,"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0437\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u0430\u0434\u0430\u043f\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430"],
[434,"\u041c\u043e\u0434\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u0430\u0434\u0430\u043f\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430"],
[435,"\u041e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043c \u043f\u0430\u043c\u044f\u0442\u0438 \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e\u0430\u0434\u0430\u043f\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430"],
[436,"HDMI"],
[439,"Display Port"],
[444,"3G"],
[445,"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0437\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0446\u0435\u0441\u0441\u043e\u0440\u0430"],
[446,"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e \u044f\u0434\u0435\u0440 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0446\u0435\u0441\u0441\u043e\u0440\u0430"],
[447,"\u0414\u0438\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043d\u0430\u043b\u044c \u0437\u043a\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430"],
[448,"\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u044d\u043a\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430"],
[449,"\u0422\u0438\u043f \u044d\u043a\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430"]],

"values":
[[80,"2048"],
[2375,"\u043d\u0435\u0442"],
[2377,"\u0435\u0441\u0442\u044c"],
[2380,"250"],
[2386,"\u0427\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439"],
[2443,"DOS"],
[2654,"DDR3"],
[2782,"4 \u044f\u0447\u0435\u0439\u043a\u0438"],
[4601,"AMD"],
[5608,"AMD"],
[5610,"2"],
[6188,"\u0435\u0441\u0442\u044c"],
[6198,"\u043d\u0435\u0442"],
[6210,"\u043d\u0435\u0442"],
[6216,"15,6\""],
[6220,"1366x768"],
[6226,"TN LED \u0433\u043b\u044f\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0439"],
[7165,"-"],
[10069,"Radeon R2"],
[10238,"AMD Dual-Core E1-6010"]],

"items":
{"70109":[[24,10238],[29,80],[42,2654],[318,2380],[320,2375],[322,2377],[323,2443],[325,2782],[328,2386],[433,4601],[434,10069],
    [435,7165],[436,6188],[439,6198],[444,6210],[445,5608],[446,5610],[447,6216],[448,6220],[449,6226]]}}
```

вот что есть на данный момент

```
     $output = curl_exec($ch); //ответ
$output = json_decode($output);                                   
$properties = array();
$values = array();
$items = array();                                             
   $fitem = fopen(__DIR__.'/items.csv','w');

foreach($output->properties as $propkey=>$prop){
   $properties[$prop[0]]=$prop[1];

}

foreach($output->values as $val){

    $values[$val[0]]=$val[1];

}                                                                
foreach($output->items as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $v){
        $items[$key][] = [$properties[$v[0]] => $values[$v[1]]];
    }
} fclose($fitem);
```

Comment: в чем проблема возникает?

Comment: пытаюсь добавить характеристики к товарам на сайте,ответ по API приходит в таком формате как я написал выше... мне помогли составить массив но я все равно не пойму как его записать в csv файл

Comment: как то так `fopen => foreach { => fputcsv =>  } fclose`. Но писать все эти три части массива  в один csv будет несколько некорректно наверное. А если в  один, тогда в первый столбец имя поля `properties/items/values` добавлять

Comment: ну по сути нужно записать только 3й миссив items так как в нем же значение properties  и values

Comment: записать то надо соответствующие текстовые значения из `props,values` ? или просточисла из items ?

Comment: да) в том-то и вся загвоздка. при разборе получается 3х мерный массив который я без понятия как записать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте возьмем тестовый JSON и декодируем его

```
$json = '{"properties": [[24,"CPU"],[29,"RAM"],[318,"HDD"],[434,"GPU"],[435,"VRAM"]],
          "values": [[80,"2048"],[2380,"250"],[10069,"Radeon R2"],[10238,"AMD Dual-Core E1-6010"],[7165,"-"]],
          "items": { "70109":[[24,10238],[29,80],[318,2380],[434,10069],[435,7165]]}}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Теперь `properties` и `values` приведем к виду массивов `24 => "CPU"` и т.п.

```
$props  = array_column($data['properties'], 1,0);
$values = array_column($data['values'], 1, 0);
```

Далее получим первый (и видимо единственный?) элемент `items`

```
$productId = key($data['items']);
$product = $data['items'][$productId];
```

иначе то же самое циклом:

```
foreach($data['items'] as $productId => $product)
```

Далее проходим по полученным парам и складываем их в массив (строку)

```
foreach($product as list($pId, $vId)){
    $row = [
            'product_id' => $productId,
            'prop' => $props[$pId],
            'value' => $values[$vId],
    ];

    print_r($row);
}
```

Для записи csv этот массив нужно будет передать в  `fputcsv($h, $row);` ну и т.п. Как я понял, проблема в обходе данных, а не записи в файл.

Comment: да!...ты правильно понял)))

Comment: @МихаилАнискин тогда не забудьте ткнуть галку, если ответ вам помог ;)